# Add-on Platform on ASP.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, add-in, platform, add-on

I want to create a web application using **ASP.Net** having an add-on platform, the system should be able to add add-ons on the fly (**add add-ons dynamically**) and make them available in the system.

**Example**: Upload a zip file (containing the code and any files required by the add-on) through a web form, when submitted the add-on can be used in the system.

I made some research but I couldn’t find a secure and with good practise example which implements an add-on platform using ASP.Net.  I was wandering if any knows about a technique/technology which I can use or any leads which may help me with my research.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/), the new Microsoft CMS. It's an open source project based on ASP.NET MVC with an add-on framework. If you're thinking of WebForms rather than MVC, try [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) or [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/), both of which are also open source CMS's with add-on capabilities (though Umbraco is in fact transitioning to MVC in the next version).